# I need the simplest way to adjust the column widths in R using datatables (or other table package)

Tags: javascript, r

I have what I'm hoping is a simple problem. I have a table which is highlighting the highest and lowest values in each row with different colors.

Now I just want to shrink the width of the 1st column as it's data should only be taking up ~3 characters across. The title is longer, so perhaps I need to allow that text to be wrapped?

Any guidance using DT or any other simple R packages would be appreciated.

I've tried "columns.width" "columnDefs" and "columns.adjust()" but nothing seems to be working.

```
sym4[1:9, 1:6] %>% datatable(options=list(rowCallback = JS(
    'function(row, data) {
    var num_data = data.slice(1,data.length)
    num_data.sort(function (a, b) {  return a - b;  });
    for(i=1;i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i]==num_data[num_data.length-1]) {
      $("td:eq("+i+")", row).css("background-color", "green")
    } else if(data[i]==num_data[num_data.length-2]) {
       $("td:eq("+i+")", row).css("background-color", "orange")
    }
    }
   }')))
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this using a sample of your data (please give to us with `dput(...)`) or with a public dataset? Please correct me if I'm wrong, but would the [tag:javascript] tag be appropriate here, too?

Comment: > iris[1:6, 1:4] %>% datatable(options=list(rowCallback = JS(
+     'function(row, data) {
+     var num_data = data.slice(1,data.length)
+     var row_max = Math.max.apply(Math,num_data);
+     var row_min = Math.min.apply(Math,num_data);
+     for(i=1;i < data.length; i++) {
+       if(data[i]==row_max) {
+         $("td:eq("+i+")", row).css("background-color", "green")
+       } else if(data[i]==row_min) {
+         $("td:eq("+i+")", row).css("background-color", "yellow")
+       }
+     }
+   }')))

Comment: thanks for your comment- see above with the iris database which I believe is public.